# Firefox doesn't open my messages on email

Tags: email, firefox

When I open my email via Hotmail, I press on some message, but it doesn't open. just appears "loading", but nothing opened. I can open them via other browsers.

But I used to work on Firefox. Any ideas?

Comment: Try Chrome. And Gmail. It's [for the greater gooooooood](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yUpbOliTHJY)

Comment: What add-ins are you running? Any other third party software that could interfere? Going through a proxy (or have a proxy set in firefox but not other browsers)?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my Hotmail account. I think they designed Hotmail to open better in Internet Explorer.

So I use [IeTab](https://addons.mozilla.org/pt-BR/firefox/addon/ie-tab-2-ff-36/) add-on and configure it to be used for Hotmail.com automatically.

Edit 1: Another alternative is to use mobile version of Hotmail via http://www.hotmail.com/m/ or http://mail.live.com/m/

Edit 2: What is your FF version? It occurred with me when I was using FF 3.6. I updated to 5.0 a week ago and I see that it does not happen...

Comment: Weird. But there is no way that they dont allow chrome and firefox to use hotmail... It works for me...

Comment: They allow, but something happens when opening messages...

Comment: If you enter for example in pages in ASP you can encounter problems with FF (at least in the past it occurred)...